# Cannot test Hbase backed by S3 from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hbase, amazon-emr

I wrote a simple program to read data from HBase, the program works find in Cloudera backed by HDFS.

But getting an exception while testing data on EMR with S3.

```
// Spark conf
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("My App");
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        // Hbase conf
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","localhost");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.client.port","2181");
        // Submit scan into hbase conf
 //       conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN, TableMapReduceUtil.convertScanToString(scan));

        conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "mytable");
        conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_START, "startrow");
        conf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_ROW_STOP, "endrow");

        // Get RDD
        JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> source = jsc
                .newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, TableInputFormat.class,
                        ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class);

        // Process RDD
        System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& " + source.count());
```

> 18/05/04 00:22:02 INFO MetricRegistries: Loaded MetricRegistries class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics.impl.MetricRegistriesImpl
>       18/05/04 00:22:02 ERROR TableInputFormat: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsInfoImpl from class
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DynamicMetricsRegistry
>         at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DynamicMetricsRegistry.newGauge(DynamicMetricsRegistry.java:139)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.(MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.java:59)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.(MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.java:51)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
>         at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
>         ... 42 more
>
> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot create a record reader because of a previous error. Please look at the previous
> ```
>
> logs lines from the task's full log for more details.
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:270)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.getSplits(TableInputFormat.java:256)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:125)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
>         at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1158)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:455)
>         at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
>         at HbaseScan.main(HbaseScan.java:60)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The input format instance has not been properly initialized. Ensure you call
>   initializeTable either in your constructor or initialize method
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getTable(TableInputFormatBase.java:652)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:265)
>         ... 20 more With ALL APACHE HBASE LIBS: e.hadoop.hbase.metrics.impl.MetricRegistriesImpl 18/05/04 04:05:54
>   ERROR TableInputFormat: java.io.IOException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.initialize(TableInputFormat.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.getSplits(TableInputFormat.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1158)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:455)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.count(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
>     at HbaseScan.main(HbaseScan.java:60)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:775)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala) Caused
>   by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
>     ... 24 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create 
>   interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSource Is
>   the hadoop compatibility jar on the classpath?    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CompatibilitySingletonFactory.getInstance(CompatibilitySingletonFactory.java:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeper.(MetricsZooKeeper.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:130)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.connect(ZKUtil.java:143)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperKeepAliveConnection.(ZooKeeperKeepAliveConnection.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveZooKeeperWatcher(ConnectionManager.java:1737)

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @PhaniKumarYadavilli . I have updated the question with the error.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this is an issue related to the JAR's. I think the JAR's associated with cloudera may not work with amazon EMR. Kindly bind the EMR associated HBase JARS's

Comment: @PhaniKumarYadavilli . Thanks so much.  But I am not using any Cloudera specific JARs and I could not find Hbase JARs from EMR https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazon.emr

Comment: Can you try using the Apache HBase related jars.

Comment: @PhaniKumarYadavilli thanks for helping me with this issue.  I carefully copied all the Apache HBase JAR for the version of HBase I am using in EMR/S3 but getting the same error.

Comment: @PhaniKumarYadavilli did not work same error.  I have attached the logs above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170336/discussion-between-alchemist-and-phani-kumar-yadavilli).

Comment: @PhaniKumarYadavilli can you please suggest any alternative... It is urgent for me to solve this.  Thanks

Comment: can you try setting the configs for HBase 

Configuration hConf = HBaseConfiguration.create(conf);
    hConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "PDHadoop1.corp.CompanyName.com,PDHadoop2.corp.CompanyName.com");
    hConf.setInt("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", 10000);

Comment: val hbaseConfiguration = (hbaseConfigFileName: String, tableName: String) => {
  val hbaseConfiguration = HBaseConfiguration.create()
  hbaseConfiguration.addResource(hbaseConfigFileName)
  hbaseConfiguration.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)
  hbaseConfiguration
  }
val rdd = sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
  hbaseConfiguration("/path/to/hbase-site.xml", "table-with-data"),
  classOf[TableInputFormat],
  classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],
  classOf[Result]
)

Comment: I am already using all the settings you have mentioned here.  Please see my complete code.

Comment: I was having the same issue because of version mismatch between HBase and hbase-spark connector. Was using HBase 1.x, but hbase-spark connector 2.0. Since I couldn't upgrade HBase to 2.x I instead downgraded hbase-spark to 1.2 (the Cloudera version). And it solved it.

Comment: Thanks so much @VS_FF I have this program working in Cloudera.  But I need to run this on EMR cluster in AWS.  I have installed HBase 1.4.0, and Spark 2.2.1.  in EMR when I got this error.

Comment: You should still be able to use the Cloudera version from here, no? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-spark?repo=cloudera By the way, not sure how you'd make Spark 2.x work -- in my experienc only Spark 1.6x works?

Comment: Thanks @VS_FF Cloudera WORKS problem is with EMR.  I have EMR installed with Spark 2.2.1runtime.  I need to run my code on Spark 2.2.1 runtime.  Cloudera was just my test env.  Finally I need to run on EMR not cloudera.  I am not using Cloudera libraries I am using Apache libraries.

Comment: Ah sorry in that case not sure what to suggest. Maybe try with HBase 2.x version? I never managed to get it up and running though with the latest releases and gave up.